# Laravel blade cache keeps restoring old views

Tags: laravel, caching, view, laravel-blade

I have some troubles with Laravel views cache now. Thanks for any help.

After pushed the latest updates to server, I did to run the commands below.

Not sure why it always shows me old content and I tried to clear the cache manually, definitely I can see the views cache files disappear at folder /storage/framework/views.

But it shows me old content in the browser always. ( But sometimes it works )

Commands

```
$ npm install -—production
$ npm run prod
$ composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
$ composer dump-autoload --optimize
$ chmod -R o+w storage
$ chmod -R o+w bootstrap/cache
$ php artisan key:generate
$ php artisan migrate --seed
$ php artisan cache:clear;  php artisan route:clear; php artisan config:clear; php artisan view:clear; php artisan event:clear;
$ php artisan config:cache ; php artisan route:cache ; php artisan view:cache ; php artisan event:cache ;
$ php artisan optimize
```

Thanks

Comment: When you use multiple consecutive commands in one line, go with `php artisan cache:clear &&  php artisan route:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan view:clear && php artisan event:clear` chaining.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this syntax in your routes/web.php, then access "url/clear-cache"

```
Route::get('clear-cache', function(){
  Artisan::call('clear-compiled');
  echo "clear-compiled: complete<br>";
  Artisan::call('cache:clear');
  echo "cache:clear: complete<br>";
  Artisan::call('config:clear');
  echo "config:clear: complete<br>";
  Artisan::call('view:clear');
  echo "view:clear: complete<br>";
  Artisan::call('optimize:clear');
  echo "optimize:clear: complete<br>";
  Artisan::call('config:cache');
  echo "config:cache: complete<br>";
  Artisan::call('view:cache');
  echo "view:cache: complete<br>";
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work, same like when I do it at command line. But found if I reload the php-fpm, I can see the content has been reload. Not sure which settings cause that issue.